# Express Session Return undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, session

I'm using express session and when trying to get information it returns undefined

```
app.use(session({
  secret: 'secret16736390',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,

}));

app.use(cors({
  origin: 'http://127.0.0.1:5500',
  credentials: true,
}));
//in order to simplify, I didn't put the complete code but it is recording and passing a valid //parameter
 req.session.participantId = result.recordset[0].MATRICULA;

app.get('/iniciarNome', async (req, res) => {
  // Obtém o ID do participante da sessão
  const user = req.session.participantId;
  console.log("Iniciar "+req.session)
```

when I do a debug in the express session it returns this

```
Login [object Object]
  app:session Conteúdo da sessão Login: Session {
  cookie: { path: '/', _expires: null, originalMaxAge: null, httpOnly: true },
  participantId: 1 obs:variable recorded
} +0ms
Iniciar [object Object]
  app:session Conteúdo da sessão Iniciar: Session {
  cookie: { path: '/', _expires: null, originalMaxAge: null, httpOnly: true }
} +202ms
undefined user obs: variable returned undefined
```

I already tried changing the cors changing the session attributes changing the browser, but I have no idea why this is happening if you can help thanks

Comment: did you `session.save()` after changes?

Comment: At the moment I'm not using it but I've tried to use it and it didn't work the same way